How to install PyMOL without disturbing the python librarys I already have installed
The official PyMOL-download includes a download of Python v.10. But I already have Python installed and are unsure how other libraries (CSV in particular) are connected to the version of Python I already have.
How do I download PyMOL without ending up with multiple version of Python
and eventually not being able to run CSV anymore see cmd-output below.
I'm not that clever when it comes to computers - so an easy explanation is prefered,
Thanks.
The versions of Python and Csv

I don't think that this is possible. The only option might be to compile pymol from source, which is not officially supported by the open source project. You can install normally though, as PyMol's python will not be added to PATH and will therefor not be invoked when you run python from cmd

I thought that was what virtual environments were for?

what version of Python does pymol come with ?

https://github.com/schrodinger/pymol-open-source/blob/master/INSTALL requirements https://github.com/schrodinger/pymol-open-source/blob/03d7a7fcf0bd95cd93d710a1268dbace2ed77765/INSTALL#L12C4-L12C18 says  - Python 3.9+ so it should be fine with you

is CSV opencv https://opencv.org/ ??

The official PyMOL-download includes a download of Python v.10.  ??? maning 3.1

You can compile opensource pymol now at version 3.0, some plug in are maybe missing and interface is older style but works as well and probably faster than license version, open source sources here : https://github.com/schrodinger/pymol-open-source. Did a test and was able to build both with python 3.8 and 3.12 , using virtual enviroment can switch between python version on your machine. Was able to build as a wheel too. If you are on windows, mac try to switch to a Linux Debian based distribution, you can run it from your PC using VMware or VBox. See @FlyingTeller comment too

https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python?tab=readme-ov-file#opencv-on-wheels seems from 3.7 to 3.12 you can find opencv-python on pypi
